# Domains, DNSes and No-Ips. Point a Domain to a no-ip.org address (using a free service?)

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, domain, redirect

I have a problem at the moment where i had registered a domain + hosting but as i was very unhappy with the hosting, i cancelled the plan and just kept the domain.

I decided to host the code locally as this is just for the scope of an assignment. I am using no-ip.org in order to point to my dynamic ip. My question is, is there a way to make my domain point to my no-ip.org url ?

Please only suggest any free services as this is just an assignment and as i purchased a domain, i might as well try and make use of it!

I was thinking of some sort of dns service which in some manner can point to the no-ip address or so? Or perhaps a free webhost which allows me to use my domain and then simply provide an html code for redirect? dont know, not really familiar with dns/ domain etc business so i would really appreciate any tips (and urls to relevant sites) please!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with no-ip.org, but I've done this sort of thing in the past with [dyndns.org](http://www.dyndns.org/), which provides free DDNS services.  First, I set up an account with dyndns; chose the name `example.dyndns.org` (it doesn't matter what name you choose, but you'll need it for the next step); then made `www.example.com` a CNAME to the dyndns hostname (`example.dyndns.org`).  Substitute your domain name for `example.com`, of course.

Comment: this doesnt really seem to be free unless i'm missing something =\

Comment: http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/.

Comment: yes, but the cname but doesnt seem to be free

Comment: You choose your .dyndns.org hostname, but then you set up the CNAME under the domain you had registered.

Answer (score 0):

I just went from using CNAMEs to dyndns A records to just using a DDNS service directly. I know dyndns does it but I'm not sure that part is free, I'm currently using Everydns.net instead.

Just add the domain you want to use to the account and run the update client on your server. To make the everydns DNS authorative for your domain you need to change the DNS servers it uses - normally made by the control panel provided by your registrar.

Comment: i've really tried this using the redirect option they have but it doesnt seem to be working for some reason :( do you have any idea which dnses i should be using i used 3 and 4 maybe i'm supposed to add the first 2?

Comment: What redirect option? Use their dynamic DNS option instead of no-ip or there's little meaning in switching DNS servers ^^ Yes use all four of the DNS servers, not that it should matter for your "not working" problem though. Changes to authoritative DNS servers can take anything from a few hours to three days or so though.

Comment: They have an option if i understood correctly to make a domain hop to another domain and thats what i really need, thats what i meant by redirect. on my domain i only have the option of adding dns addresses only tho

Answer (score 0):

Just make your domain name's `@` record a CNAME to your `no-ip.org` domain. Also, make the TTL very low since your IP might change and you don't want cache issues to get on your users.

Comment: how does one go about changing the domain's @ record pls?

Comment: If you bought a domain name, your registrar probably provides an interface to manage DNS entries. Set the entry for the domain name to be a CNAME to your `no-ip.org` domain.

Comment: You can not use a `CNAME` for the `@` record in DNS.  `CNAME`s are not allowed to exist with other record types and the `@` record in a domain has (at a minimum) the `SOA` and `NS` records as well.